# Cucumber - How to call scenario 1 steps in scenario 2?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

I'm working on Cucumber-Java project. I've a situation where I have to use all steps in scenario 1 into scenario 2 and add few more steps. Instead of copying all steps from scenario 1 to scenario 2, is there better way to just call scenario name in scenario 2 or something ?

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic approach is to organize your tests in the way where all common starting common steps are executed in `Background` section.

Non-idiomatic and not recommended (but still possible) is to call your step definition methods straight from `Before` hook of your scenario.

You can find some examples here https://www.baeldung.com/java-cucumber-background